Why does my query in Vertica execute itself multiple times?
I'm new to Vertica and trying to insert data into a table by aggregating data from another table using DBeaver. My query looks something like this:
INSERT INTO target_table
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT colA
    FROM tableA
    WHERE = 'xxx'
)
SELECT colA, colB, colC, COUNT(DISTINCT colD) AS cnt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM tableB
WHERE colA NOT IN (SELECT colA FROM CTE)
GROUP BY CUBE(colA, colB, colC);

However, after running for 4 hours, I checked query_requests and noticed that the query keeps generating new requests automatically (as its first request had already finished by the first hour) and inserting data into the table repeatedly. It won't stop until I cancel the query, resulting in duplicate records with different timestamps being inserted.
This issue occurs when tableB contains more than 50 million records. If the number of records is less than that, the query runs without any problems.
What could be causing this behavior, and how can I prevent the query from executing multiple times?

Can you share the output of an EXPLAIN of the command? and also of SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','tableA',FALSE). ? It could be several HASH GROUPBYs , each of which turn out to not fit in memory at different points in time, causing an automatic restart, spilling the hash table to disk instead trying to keep it in memory, without clearing the already inserted rows.

@marcothesane For SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','tableA',FALSE), it shows SEGMENTED BY hash(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8). And for EXPLAIN, there are 2 rows associated to GROUPBY HASH
| +---> GROUPBY HASH (SORT OUTPUT) (GLOBAL RESEGMENT GROUPS) (LOCAL RESEGMENT GROUPS) [Cost: 47M, Rows: 67M] (PATH ID: 3)
| | +---> GROUPBY HASH (GLOBAL RESEGMENT GROUPS) (LOCAL RESEGMENT GROUPS) [Cost: 29M, Rows: 67M] (PATH ID: 4)
Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue if it's due to memory?

Your problem can source from want of memory.
But of course, you have two heavy GROUPBY-s that go both into GLOBAL RESEGMENTATION (which takes long, as rows need to travel from node to node) and go into HASH .
I suppose you have one GROUPBY PIPELINED in the plan, too - and also that one with GLOBAL RESEGMENTATION.
I suggest you create a new projection on tableB:
CREATE PROJECTION <schema>.tableB_col123 AS
SELECT
  *
FROM tableB
ORDER BY col1,col2,col3
SEGMENTED BY HASH(col1,col2,col3) ALL NODES;

I assume the GROUP BY col1,col2,col3 is the one with a cost of 47M - PATH ID 3.
.. and then ...
SELECT REFRESH('<schema>.tableB');

.. and then re-run the INSERT ... SELECT in the hope it won't hog as much memory.
